# MySQL Replication: Using HAProxy and an HTTP-Check

Tags: mysql, replication, haproxy

I read the Github engineering [article](http://githubengineering.com/context-aware-mysql-pools-via-haproxy/) on MySQL Replication with  HAProxy.  One paragraph of note to me is:

> In this situation, HAProxy no longer uses a mysql-check but rather an
>   http-check. The MySQL backend server provides an HTTP interface,
>   responding with HTTP 200 or HTTP 503 depending on replication lag.
>   HAProxy will interpret these as “good” (UP) or “bad” (DOWN),
>   respectively.

I am not aware of any MySQL HTTP Service.  Is this a custom script that I have to write to provide this type of http-check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not provide an http service to report its slave lag.

If you read further in the article you linked to, they wrote a section heading "Implementing the check script" which describes the custom script they wrote to provide this report.

They link to the script, which is written in bash:

https://github.com/github/mysql-haproxy-xinetd/blob/master/scripts/xinetd-mysql-check-lag